# angularJS increment/decrement current route with next/previous buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/342MvXDwWG7RlIxB0JB1?p=preview

I need to use "prev" & "next" buttons to switch to the next or previous route index.
i.e. when on page route article/0, you can click "next", and the page will route to and display article/1. Can someone help?

javascript:

```
FeedApp.controller("ArticlesCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    var index = $routeParams.articleId;
    console.log(index);

    $scope.article = {};

    $http.get('news-html.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.news.push(data);
      $scope.article = $scope.news[0].entries[index];
    });
  }
]);

FeedApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

 .when("/", {
   controller: "NewsCtrl",
   templateUrl: "home.html"
 })

  .when("/article/:articleId", {
   controller: "ArticlesCtrl",
   templateUrl: "article.html"
 })

 .otherwise({
   redirectTo: "/"
 });


});
```

html for page with buttons:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <a href="#/"><button>Back</button></a>
  <a href="#/??"><button id="prev">Prev</button></a>
  <a href="#/??"><button id="next">Next</button></a>
</div>

<h2>{{article.title}}</h2>

<div ng-bind-html="article.content | trustHTML"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get it working but I couldn't quite understand your data structure.

You can add 1 or minus 1 from the current index for previous and next buttons:

First you need to convert current index to an int and add it to scope:

```
$scope.index = parseInt($routeParams.articleId);
```

Then in the view you can add 1 or minus 1 from the current index for the buttons. I've also used the ng-show binding so that the buttons won't show if there is no next article. You will need to replace array with your array variable that has the articles in.

```
<a href="#/acticle/{{index - 1}}" ng-show="index > 0"><button id="prev">Prev</button></a>
<a href="#/acticle/{{index + 1}}" ng-show="index < news[0].length-1"><button id="next">Next</button></a>
```